# Как заставить пользователя вновь выбирать нужный вариант ответа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, if, условия

Как "заставить" пользователя заново выбирать одну из предложенных цифр, если он решил пойти против "правил"?

```
print ("Добро пожаловать")
trin = input ("""Каким путём ты хочешь пойти?
1. Простым.
2. Сложным. """)
if trin == '1':
    print ("Как скажешь. ")
if trin == '2':
    prin ("Так держать!")
else:
    print ("Такого варианта нет, выбери цифру ещё раз. ")
```

У меня есть предположения, что это делается через циклы, но не знаю,

Как это правильно написать, чтобы всё работало?

Comment: не надо заставлять, пользователь - не игрушка!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно и через циклы:

```
print("Добро пожаловать!")

trin = None

while trin not in ['1', '2']:
    trin = input("""Каким путём ты хочешь пойти?
    1. Простым.
    2. Сложным. """)

    if trin == '1':
        print("Как скажешь.")
    elif trin == '2':
        print("Так держать!")
    else:
        print("Такого варианта нет, выбери цифру ещё раз. ")

print("Спасибо за сделанный выбор")
```

Comment: Кст, вместо `trin not in ['1', '2']` можно было так `trin not in '12'`, или вовсе проверить на `True`: `while not trin:`

Comment: 1. согласен; 2. нет, если  trin что-то помимо 1 или 2, нужно переспрашивать

Comment: ага, затупил насчет **2.** :)

Comment: prin ("Так держать!") - нет t.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru prin trin, trin prin ))

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
print("Добро пожаловать")

while True:
    trin = input("""Каким путём ты хочешь пойти?
    1. Простым.
    2. Сложным.""")
    if trin == '1':
        print("Как скажешь. ")
    if trin == '2':
        print("Так держать!")
    else:
        print("Такого варианта нет, выбери цифру ещё раз. ")
        continue
    
    # Выход из цикла
    break
```

Comment: или поставить break-и в тело `if trin == '1'` и `if trin == '2'`

Comment: @Jack_oS, думаю, лучше один раз написать `break` и `continue`, чем без `continue` зато с кучей `break` :)